# Test if kafka ready, topics are reachable from cli

Tags: apache-kafka

Was looking around and couldn't find anything other than kafka-topic --list. 
I'm running Kafka in a K8s environment and have an init container that creates a couple of topics. I want my main container to start only when the topics are created and the topics are "subscribable" to. kafka-topic --list I believe is just reaching zookeeper as I can see my pod is showing error messages about the topic.

I did try kafka-console-consumer but even if the topic is not present it doesn't exit with status 1. It does exit with status one if the bootstrap server is not reachable. I'm looking for a solution similar to below

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server correct-bootstrap-server:9092 --topic correct-topic --timeout-ms 100
```

exits with 0 ( this one works )

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server wrong-bootstrap-server:9092 --topic wrong-topic --timeout-ms 100
```

exits with a non zero exit code (this one works too).

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server correct-bootstrap-server:9092 --topic wrong-topic --timeout-ms 100
```

exits with a non zero exit code ( this one doesn't work as it exits with code 0)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not totally trivial to make sure from CLI if a Kafka topic is "ready". Many things can go wrong.

We had the same issues, and the current approach we are taking involves several call to the kafka-topic CLI

1. We make sure the topic exists with `kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic FOO`
2. Check that all partitions have a leader `kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic FOO --unavailable-partitions` (output should be empty)
3. Check that all partitions are fully replicated `kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic FOO --under-replicated-partitions`  (output should be empty)

That still doesn't make it 100% certain that the topic is "ready", but it works for us

Answer (score 1):

`kafka-topics` can list under-replicated, offline and under-min-isr partitions.
The best bet is to check that your topic is not under-replicated. If it isn't, it should be ready.